# Query to fetch data for list of regular expressions given

Tags: regex, postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have to fetch data for given list of regular expressions. for single regular expression below query is working but for list i am facing issue

```
select id from res r where 
(?1 is null or CAST(r.value AS TEXT) ~ cast(?1 as TEXT));
```

`?1` is `[^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$]` and it is working fine

Now when i put list of regular expressions then `[^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$, 75$]` it is not working

Comment: What is the type of the parameter ?1 - is it a nullable text array ?

Comment: it is the List of regular expressions... that is array @Stefanov.sm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `?1` type is text array (`text[]`) or a valid textual representation of text array syntax then

```sql
select id from res r where 
?1 is null
or exists (select from unnest(?1::text[]) rx where r.value::text ~ rx);
```

Please note that the syntax of the text array of regular expressions shall not be
`[^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$, 75$]` but `{"^\\d{3}\\d{1,}133\\d{1,}$", 75$}`

**Edit**
It might be a good idea to define a function that returns `true` if the first argument matches *any* of the regular expressions in an array. Something similar to a non-existent but good to have `REGEX_IN` operator.

```sql
create or replace function regex_any(needle text, haystack_rules text[])
returns boolean language sql immutable as $$
    select exists (select from unnest(haystack_rules) haystack_rule where needle ~ haystack_rule);
$$;
```

Then your query will look like this:

```sql
select id from res r 
 where ?1 is null 
 or regex_any(r.value::text, ?1);
```

Comment: tried 1st query , it is giving result of endswith regex e.g  '{"75$","22$"}' ... but it is not giving results of starts with regex e.g {"^\d{3}7483"}  and contains regex '{"^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$"}'                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                        
 select id from res r where  
?1 is null
or exists (select from unnest(?1::text[]) rx where r.value::text ~ rx);

Comment: Strange. Pls. post sample data. Maybe there are leading spaces?

Comment: select id from res r where 
'{"^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$"}' is null
or exists (select from unnest('{"^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$"}'::text[]) rx where r.value::text ~ rx); pls check this.

Comment: select id from res r where 
'{"^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$","^\d{3}7483"}' is null
or exists (select from unnest('{"^\d{3}\d{1,}133\d{1,}$","^\d{3}7483"}'::text[]) rx where r.value::text ~ rx);
this is for multiple regex patterns

Comment: My omission. You have to escape (i.e. double) the backslashes like this: `{"^\\d{3}\\d{1,}133\\d{1,}$","^\\d{3}7483"}`

Comment: This is giving error when we pass null to the parameter .   ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to text[] @Stefanov.sm

Comment: Make the function `strict`, i.e. `language sql immutable strict as` ...

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE), the `~` operator works against a single regular expression. You would need to update your query to work against a list of regular expressions. For example,

```sql
select id from res r where 
(?1 is null or (select bool_and(r.value::text ~ x.exp) FROM unnest(?1)))
```

The second part of the where returns true if the column matches *all* regular expressions in ?1. Depending on the size of your input, you can extract unnest(?1) into a CTE.

Comment: This is giving  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select" @svetha.cvl